# Play framework: How do I define the timezone for the date entered by a user?

Tags: data-binding, date, playframework, timezone

In my play framework app the user has the choice to enter a date for a schedule, the date is then mapped to my model entity:

```
@InFuture
@As("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
public Date validFrom;
```

This is the field in the form

```
<input type="text" name="schedule.validFrom" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm">
```

The problem is that our server is running in a non-local time zone and the timezone should be taken from the object where this schedule is being made for.

So I know upfront what the timezone is for this schedule and I don't want the user having to enter the timezone in the field.

A possible solution would be to submit the date as string and do manual validation and parsing but I wonder if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Manual parsing is probably your best option.
You could possibly create your own object containing the date and the timezone.
Then implement your own validation check based on [InFutureCheck](http://massapi.com/source/play-1.2.2/framework/src/play/data/validation/InFutureCheck.java.html) and perform the timezone conversion.

Comment: actually went for the solution of modifying the dates before validation/storing: dateTime.toLocalDateTime().toDateTime(timeZone); It's not that clean but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The better option will be to give user a drop down list of timezones. For example:

```
String TIMEZONE_ID_PREFIXES ="^(Africa|America|Asia|Atlantic|Australia|Europe|Indian|Pacific)/.*";
String[] ids = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
Timezone tz = null;
for (int i=0; i<ids.length; i++) {
  if (ids[i].matches(TIMEZONE_ID_PREFIXES)) {  
    //add TimeZone.getTimeZone(ids[i]).getDisplayName() to a drop down list
  }
}
```

Comment: the schedules are linked to locations which have a fixed timezone, no need for a dropdown

Answer (score 0):

The best practice here really depends on whether your users need to see multiple timezones.

- If they do not need multiple timezones, then you can assume all times are 'zone-less' aka they are all UTC or GMT.  This is *by far* the simplest option.
- If users need to see multiple timezones, then you are best off passing the timezone with each date with the Z parameter: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone Meanwhile, in Javascript, you will probably want to use a library to create a date string with a timezone, such as: http://arshaw.com/xdate/#Formatting